# Postgres don't start after an unexpected shutdown

Tags: postgresql

After an unexpected shutdown in postgres 8.4, I'm getting this error.

```
couldn't open the file 'pg_xlog/....'. No such file or directory.
invalid primary checkpoint record.
```

Complete message in portuguese:

> 2014-05-13 16:46:04 BRT [5980]: [1-1] LOG:  sistema de banco de dados
>   foi interrompido; última execução em 2014-05-13 15:46:07 BRT
>   2014-05-13 16:46:04 BRT [5980]: [2-1] LOG:  não pôde abrir arquivo
>   "pg_xlog/00000001000001A1000000ED" (arquivo de log 417, segmento 237):
>   No such file or directory 2014-05-13 16:46:04 BRT [5980]: [3-1] LOG: 
>   registro do ponto de controle é inválido 2014-05-13 16:46:04 BRT
>   [5980]: [4-1] PÂNICO:  não pôde localizar registro do ponto de
>   controle requerido 2014-05-13 16:46:04 BRT [5980]: [5-1] DICA:  Se
>   você não está restaurando uma cópia de segurança, tente remover o
>   arquivo "C:/Arquivos de programas/PostgreSQL/8.4/data/backup_label".
>
> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an
>   unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more
>   information.
>
> 2014-05-13 16:46:04 BRT [5440]: [1-1] LOG:  processo de inicialização
>   (PID 5980) terminou com código de retorno 3 2014-05-13 16:46:04 BRT
>   [5440]: [2-1] LOG:  interrompendo inicialização porque o processo de
>   inicialização falhou

I read about it and the only option it seems to execute pg_resetxlog.exe.

> pg_resetxlog -- reset the write-ahead log and other control information of a PostgreSQL database cluster.
>
> You should immediately dump your data, run initdb, and reload. After
>   reload, check for inconsistencies and repair as needed.

But according to documentation this should be the last resource.

Any other ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the exact error message?  You said there are files in pg_xlog, but is the specific file named in the error message present?  Do you know what else the person who killed the postgres process may have done in addition?

Comment: **Before you do anything else, read and act on this: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption**. Now: What's the backstory here - how did you get to this point? Did you move/delete something? Operating system crash? Disk error? ... ? What's the exact, unedited error message without the `....`s? In another comment you say *"someone kill[ed] the postgres process and now it doesn't start"*. What exact commands were run? Why was it killed?

Comment: The exact message is in portuguese, I'll update the message. They just killed the process with the task manager, after it didn't started anymore.